# Selenium use without testing?

Tags: web-services, selenium

As I know Selenium use as a web UI functional testing tool.Is there any tool that I can use instead of selenium.I mean I do not want to test the web site.But I want to use functionalities like Selenium.Can I do that using selenium or is there any tool that I can use for this?

thanxx

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do?  If you just need something that can control a web browser and mimic activity on the page(s) within that browser, [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty good library.

Comment: thanxx for quick response,Think this way I want to check currency rate frequently from a web site,That site contains,I want to go to that site,Enter the currency(Rs) and get the converted value($) from that site.What is the best way I can do this??pls let me know how i can do this. I have no idea how to do this

Comment: @123Ex: It sounds like you're trying to do screen scraping from an application, rather than actually "using" a site from that application.  What language/environment are you using?  Basically, you need some kind of HTTP Client library (like System.Net.WebClient for .NET) and a DOM parser to parse values out of the site's HTML.

Comment: I'm working on java environment,I'm familiar xpath,but I'm new to this area so please suggest me what are the good technologies that i can use for this,thanxx

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC + Bromine will only serve this purpose.Write a java program to enter some currrency value,and retrieve the $ value and save the test case.Schedule the test case in bromine . Is this wat u wer looking for?

Comment: sounds like good but the thing is,I don't wanna use as a test case I want to use as program.so can I do this using selenium?Is there any language that I can use for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a loop which accesses the web site getting / checking the currency conversion at set intervals.

The tool to use for this is Selenium RC.

See [Selenium RC : Importing a script from Selenium IDE](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/10/selenium-rc-importing-script-from.html) for an example.

This is using Netbeans / JUnit as a wrapper.

Then you just need an assert and throw an exception when the answer is not what you are looking for.

Selenium RC allows you to write Java code so it is trivial to have loops / checks / waits / timeouts etc.

Because it is JUnit you can take it outside of Netbeans if you want and simply run from a command line.

Another solution would be to use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze what exactly is being sent to the web site and then code that using the standard Java HTTP POST / GET functionality e.g. [Sending a POST Request Using a URL](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html)